# scanf 2d array size C

Tags: c

I've tried to make custom array size by:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    int y;

    printf("Array size:");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

    int kancelar[x][y];
    int i;
    int q;

    for (q = 0; q < x; q++)
        for (i = 0; i < y; i++)
            kancelar[q][i] = getchar();

    for (q = 0; q < x; q++)
        for (i = 0; i < y; i++)
            putchar(kancelar[q][i]);

    return 0;
}
```

But no luck, values were wrong. I'm using C,

Comment: What was wrong? Please clarify

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'values are wrong'? What values did you get and what values did you expect to get?

Comment: How can i paste code to comments?

Comment: @DanielKubica, it's not a problem, it's a _requirement_. But still, this should be a minimal code example, not some huge code

Comment: You should dynamically allocate memory, using `malloc` functions.

Comment: @DanielKubica you edit your question instead

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QysV9jaf

I can write unlimited characters, and if the array is [2][3] it'll ask only for 1 line. for example.

Comment: idk, i'm using GNU GCC compiler built in Code::Blocks

Comment: `scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);` --> `scanf("%d %d%*c",&x,&y);` , show your input.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY still wrong :(

Comment: @BLUEPIXY mind each `getchar()`.... in the loop. :)

Comment: @DanielKubica Show your input. and Explain the _values were wrong_.

Comment: What C version are you using? C89 or C99?

Comment: you declare a 2d array of ints but read characters, is this really what you want?

Comment: so by first loop i don't add characters?

Idk what version i'm using but it's most probably C89

Answer (score 1):

You are getting messed up by the `newline`s present in the input buffer by the press of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after each input. You need to consume the newline each time before going for the `getchar()`.

A simple solution may look like

```
printf("Array size:");
scanf("%d %d%*c",&x,&y);  //eat up the newline
int kancelar[x][y];
int i;
int q;
for(q = 0;q < x;q++)
{
    for(i = 0;i < y;i++ )
    {
        kancelar[q][i] = getchar();
        getchar(); //eat up newline
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, but now it gave me 5 lines of input when  wanted 3x4 array, and output is still wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
int kancelar[x][y];
```

You cannot create an array with variable values, you can do this with only constant values. So to create a custom array you need to allocate memory for you array dynamically

I have taken this code from this link : [LINK](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int r, c;
    scanf("%d %d",&r,&c);

    // allocating memory
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(r * c * sizeof(int));

    int i, j, count = 0;
    // giving them default values
    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
         *(arr + i*c + j) = ++count;

    // printing the values 
    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
         printf("%d ", *(arr + i*c + j));

   // free memory
   free(arr);

   return 0;
}
```

Check out the link as they show **more than one ways** to achieve this

Comment: yes you can, it is called VLA i.e. if you have a C99 compiler (or later) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array

Comment: 1)Remove the cast from `malloc` as it is unneccessary 2)Declare `r` and `c` 3)`free` the allocated memory

Comment: @AndersK. Did not know that.

Comment: @CoolGuy Thanks! about #1 malloc returns void pointer, don't we need to cast it first? [malloc reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)

Comment: @sami1592 `void*` is automatically converted. Read [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/3049655)